# Adding rows to Excel sheet based on groups of 4 using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I do not know much about VBA coding and it seems to be the only way to solve this. I am trying to add rows based on sets that are not 4. So if the data in either column F or I, does not add up to a set of 4, it must add the required number of rows below the existing rows. I manually added the yellow rows as an example. The Blue row requires 2 extra lines below it, the green rows requires 1 extra row below it to make up 4. If there were only 1, it would have to add 3 rows below it. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Excel_Sample]

Comment: What have you tried so far? 1. Whenever you need to add rows you need to loop from bottom to top (otherwise counting rows goes wrong. So loop from bottom to top and compare the values in `F` and `I` with the row above (to see if they changed). Count to 4 while doing that and if there is a change before you count to 4 there need to be added rows. Eg If you counted to 2 then you need to add 2 rows. Give it a try and show your attempt in your question ([edit]).

Answer (score 0):

We found non-excel based solution with the software (QGIS) that is used to generate the excel data. The software now outputs to excel with the rows already added. Thanks in any case.